# Disable anti-aliasing in google chrome or firefox

Tags: 20.04, firefox, google-chrome, antialiasing

I installed `gnome-tweaks` and disabled anti-aliasing but it did not change the fonts in google chrome or firefox. How do I disable anti-aliasing in google chrome or firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have knowledge about Chrome but you can disable anti-aliasing in Firefox with;

1. Go to `about:config`
2. Search for `gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.rendering_mode` change it to `1` (ref: https://superuser.com/a/563845) **Edit:** This answer is very old but you can try it.
3. Change `gfx.text.disable-aa` to True. (This one completely disables AA)

Comment: thanks, the third solution worked